# How should router.renavigate() be used?

Tags: angular, url-routing

In a components three levels deep I have an ajax call that updates data on the server, which is being displayed in the parent and grand parent control.

I wish to navigate to the current url shown in the browser which should reinitialise the grand parent control and fetch new data from the server.

If I call router.navigate(...) or router.navigateByUrl(...) with the same url details, nothing happens.

If I add a time stamp as a parameter, so that the url changes, then everything works the way I expect it would.

I saw in another post, a user mentioned using router.renavigate(), which sounds perfect, but apparently it doesn't work either (at least for the situation above.)

Is this a bug or is it as per design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5916#issuecomment-214303206

> ts not a bug per say. router.renavigate isn't meant for navigating again in the case that you configure your routes dynamically at runtime. router.lastNavigationAttempt is only updated when router.navigateByUrl is called. The navigateByUrl is called on initial load and unless you use it manually it won't get called again because the other navigation functions such as router.navigate and router.navigateByInstruction don't update the lastNavigationAttempt either.

I would rather bind the data to a service and update the data in the service and design the components in a way that they automatically update themselves when the shared data changes.

Comment: Thanks for finding that thread, I tried to have a look but came up empty handed.

Its a pity this will not work, it was a simple solution to the issue, I was hoping to avoid having to implement something like a service to get the page to update, especially in this example which seemed trivial, but I guess there is no point swimming against the current.